# insert into sqlite db with java is not working

Tags: java, sqlite

I already inserted to this DB file from other classes in my project but I don't know why isn't the code working this time , when I insert from cmd it works , but using this code isn't working anymore,the client table is empty nowand still not working can anyone help me guess the problem please ?

```
SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection gtcn=new SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection(); 


private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    System.out.println(""+id);
      String ss[]=new String[] {};ss=jTextField1.getText().split(" ");
      System.out.println(ss[0]+""+ss[1]);


    String sql="insert into client(ID,NAME,LASTNAME,
    COMPANYNAME,clientEmail,clientPhon) "
   + " values("+id+",'"+ss[0]+"','"+ss[1]+"','"+
   jTextField6.getText()+"','"
   +jTextField7.getText()+"','"
   +jTextField5.getText()+"')";

   try { cn=gtcn.getConnection();
         cn.setAutoCommit(false);
            //  pst=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
             // id++;
         stmm=cn.createStatement();
         stmm.executeUpdate(sql);
              System.out.println(""+sql);
// TODO add your handling code here:
          } catch (SQLException ex) {

              Logger.getLogger(NewCreation.class.getName()).
              log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }

    }
```

Comment: no errors shown , and sql query is printed which means no exceptions, I still have no idea how I m getting trouble with this

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? are you expecting a particular result you're not seeing?

Comment: when I write select query in command prompt no result inserted from the app I can only insert using cmd , thank you

Comment: which command prompt you use? what are the working directory paths for your 'cmd prompt' and the app? what is the jdbc connection url in both cases?

Comment: All implemented in this class SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection and it work in other classes , I have no idea why it's not working in the action performed of that button (the code above) so now I'm connecting and closing connection each time I need a DB operation that's fine till now but I still want to understand why the above is happening I know it may be a bug , thanks